# Is it normal for 24" LED monitor to emit 1000 odd mV/m?

Tags: emf

I have a 24" LED monitor, we have a cell phone tower on a building next to ours, so we bought an EMF meter to see if there was any high radiation from it. Throughout the house, the radiation was above 600 mV/m sometimes it fluctuated to 400 mV/m. Is this safe or normal? As one might expect, there was above 1 V/m near WiFi routers.

But what struck me as odd was monitor, it is 24", LED, and near some spots, it was emitting more than 1000 odd mV/m. Is this normal? There was no known WiFi device near the monitor. It was emitting the same amount, regardless of whether the monitor was on or off.

Comment: 1000mV = 1Volt.

Comment: What meter would that be?

Comment: It'd surprise the stuffing out of me if your "EMF meter" could reliably detect anything from the cell phone tower at all.

Comment: You think that's bad? "In areas of fair weather, the atmospheric electric field near the earth's surface typically is about **100 volts (V) m-1**" http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Atmospheric_electric_field.

Comment: Most likely most of your results are caused by mains wiring inside walls. The monitor seems to emit but it did have a live power cord, right? It is not known if 1V/m is normal for your monitor, but let's put that into perspective: five monitors would equal a light bulb, and 80 monitors would equal a hair dryer. Standard 9V battery terminals are less than 1cm apart, so field strength between terminals would be over 900 V/m.

Comment: you are probably picking up a ghost that is using the monitor

Comment: What kind of "EMF meter"? What frequency are you measuring?

Comment: @Justme The EMF meter is 3 axis EMF, ELF & RF meter, here is a link: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/653481078.html

Comment: @Justme The EMF meter I showed has different modes for EMF, ELF & RF, if it was due to wiring, wouldn't that be shown in a mode for ELF? I cannot guess how the wiring runs through the walls, but RF, EMF ratings showed high near the place I sleep and near ends of curtain rods, there were no power sources there. Anything from wiring would be in ELF, right?

Answer (score 1):

We can put your measurements into the following perspective:

When a designer of an electrical device wants to conduct EMI immunity tests, at least in Europe the device needs to withstand at least 3V/m without showing any effects. (10V/m for industrial devices)

So 1V/m should not be a big concern.

Comment: Consider however that the absorption of energy increases with frequency into a dielectric and it you start you get bloodshot eyes, you know who to blame.

Comment: You are saying devices should be able to withstand 3V/m but should humans be constantly be exposed to 1V/m?

Comment: We humans are not electronic circuits, so we do not react to magnetic fields (but if the fields are VERY strong, we might react on the heat that is generated).